# wget: can't open : File exists

Tags: shell

I use shell scripts to call a restful API with wget. However, it works only for the first time, and in the 2nd time, it throws an error---wget: can't open : File exists

The restful API is supposed not to return any value but just insert some records to db on server.

How to fix this?

```
while read line; do wget  http://resturl done
```

Comment: Is there an existing file in the way? In my experience, wget will increment the download file name if one by an existing name exists, but check anyway. Consider specifying an incrementing output name to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Try specifying your own output file: `-O-` for stdout or `-O/dev/null` if you don't care.

Comment: Well I have no idea about restful API but wget is going to download the remote file. Since it is in a while loop, it is going to give that error when it does it second time. Expected behavior.

Comment: How, if at all, is `line` related to `resturl`? If it is, just test for the existence of the file before calling wget. e.g.: `do [ -e "$fname" ] || wget http://resturl; done`. If you are not parsing `line` to get `resturl`, then just ignore.

Comment: Without a `;` before the `done`, this isn't even valid bash syntax; it can't possibly be a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Because there is already a downloaded file exists in your working directory, that's why it works for the first time for you.